# editActionsForRowAtIndexPath is not called when UITableView contains a SearchBar

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a UITableView with SearchBar and I want to add some custom slide out buttons. This is achieved by overriding `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` and `canEditRowAtIndexPath`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? 
{
    var editRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Edit", handler: {action, indexPath in println("Edit row action")})
    editRowAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)

    var deleteRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete", handler: {action, indexPath in println("Delete row action")})

    return [deleteRowAction, editRowAction]
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool 
{
    return true
}
```

Buttons are added and work as expected, but just on "filtered" TableView, i.e. TableView that shows filtered search results. Nothing happens when I swipe cells in "main" TableView that shows unfiltered data.

Same code works fine for another TableView that has no SearchBar attached.

Overrided methods of `UISearchBarDelegate` and `UISearchDisplayDelegate` are as follows:

```
func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool 
{
    let scopes = self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles as! [String]
    let selectedScope = scopes[self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex] as String
    self.filterContentForSearchTest(searchString, scope: selectedScope)
    return true
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchScope searchOption: Int) -> Bool 
{
    let scopes = self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles as! [String]
    let selectedScope = scopes[self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex] as String
    self.filterContentForSearchTest(self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.text, scope: selectedScope)
    return true
}
```

Is it expected behaviour? How can I make cells swipable on both TableViews?